# Retain observable from error and return all values

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

Hello I have something like:

```
Observable.fromIterable(0..4)
        .map { if (it == 3) throw Exception() else it }
        .subscribe { println(it) }
```

I wish it to return all values except one (it == 3 must be skipped due to error). How could it be done?

Comment: did you mean `.filter { it != 3 }`

Comment: I just mentioned that some observable throws an error, and I wanted to skip that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done for example with wrapping in `Maybe`:

```kotlin
Observable.fromIterable(0..4)
    .flatMapMaybe {
        Maybe.fromCallable { if (it == 3) throw Exception() else it }
            .onErrorComplete()
    }
    .subscribe { println(it) }
```